# Python KeyError exception / exiting code without error

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, keyerror

I got a rather weird problem. The following code in scrape1 sometimes works as it should, but most of the time it just stops at line 24, where request.get is being used. I do however consistently get this keyerror exception:

> Exception KeyError: KeyError(140186412830800,) in module <'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored

The exception is only thrown when I'm importing the module proxyfetch.py but as long as I don't actually execute the code in proxyfetch.py, scrape1.py doesn't break (exception is thrown after nominal execution). Proxyfetch is based on DanMcInerney elite-proxy-finder on github. I just edited it so I could use it as a module which returns a list of proxys instead of printing them.

So here are the 2 scripts:
**scrape1.py:**

```
#scrape1.py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from proxyfetch import getprox
import requests


proxcount=3

listz = getprox(proxcount)
proxfile = open("proxysave.txt", "w")

base_url = "http://google.com"
def pagefetch(url):
    print "Test"
    http_proxy = "http://"+listz[0]
    #http_proxy = "http://103.25.203.227:3127"
    print "Test2"
    proxydict = {
                "http"  : http_proxy
                #"https_proxy"  : https_proxy
                }

    print "Test3"
    page = requests.get(url, proxies=proxydict) #with proxy
    #page = requests.get(url) #without proxy
    print "Test4"
    return page
page = pagefetch(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
links = soup.find_all("a")

if links:
        for n in links:
            print n
else:
    print "I got nuthin."
```

And **proxyfetch.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#proxyfetch.py
'''Finds hundreds of elite anonymity (L1) HTTP proxies then tests them all in parallel printing the fastest ones first.
Checks headers to confirm eliteness, checks if compatible with opening HTTPS sites, and confirms the proxy is working
through multiple IP checking sites'''

# TO DO:
# -Add http://free-proxy-list.net/
# -Add hidemyass
#from IPython import embed

__author__ = 'Dan McInerney'
__contact__ = 'danhmcinerney gmail'

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import requests
import ast
import gevent
import sys, re, time, os, argparse
import socket
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
listz =[]

def getprox(amount):
    argz = [amount, False, True]
    try:
        P = find_http_proxy(argz)
        P.run()
    except BaseException,Err:
        return listz
    return listz

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--show', help='Show this number of results. Example: "-s 5" will show the 5 fastest proxies then stop')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--all', help='Show all proxy results including the ones that failed 1 of the 3 tests', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', help='Only print the IP:port of the fastest proxies that pass all the tests', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()

class find_http_proxy():
    ''' Will only gather L1 (elite anonymity) proxies
    which should not give out your IP or advertise
    that you are using a proxy at all '''
    #argz = [arg1, False, True]
    def __init__(self, argz):
        self.proxy_list = []
        self.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36'}
        self.show_num = argz[0]
        self.show_all = False
        self.quiet = True
        self.errors = []
        self.print_counter = 0
        self.externalip = self.external_ip()

    def external_ip(self):
        req = requests.get('http://myip.dnsdynamic.org/', headers=self.headers)
        ip = req.text
        return ip

    def run(self):
        ''' Gets raw high anonymity (L1) proxy data then calls make_proxy_list()
        Currently parses data from gatherproxy.com and letushide.com '''

        if not self.quiet:
            print '[*] Your accurate external IP: %s' % self.externalip

        letushide_list = self.letushide_req()
        if not self.quiet:
            print '[*] letushide.com: %s proxies' % str(len(letushide_list))

         # Has a login now :(
        gatherproxy_list = self.gatherproxy_req()
        if not self.quiet:
            print '[*] gatherproxy.com: %s proxies' % str(len(gatherproxy_list))

        checkerproxy_list = self.checkerproxy_req()
        if not self.quiet:
            print '[*] checkerproxy.net: %s proxies' % str(len(checkerproxy_list))

        self.proxy_list.append(letushide_list)
        self.proxy_list.append(gatherproxy_list)
        self.proxy_list.append(checkerproxy_list)

        # Flatten list of lists (1 master list containing 1 list of ips per proxy website)
        self.proxy_list = [ips for proxy_site in self.proxy_list for ips in proxy_site]
        self.proxy_list = list(set(self.proxy_list)) # Remove duplicates

        if not self.quiet:
            print '[*] %d unique high anonymity proxies found' % len(self.proxy_list)
            print '[*] Testing proxy speeds ...'
            print ''
            print '      Proxy           | CC  |       Domain          | Time/Errors'

        self.proxy_checker()
        return list_
    def checkerproxy_req(self):
        ''' Make the request to checkerproxy and create a master list from that site '''
        cp_ips = []
        try:
            url = 'http://checkerproxy.net/all_proxy'
            r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
            html = r.text
        except Exception:
            print '[!] Failed to get reply from %s' % url
            checkerproxy_list = []
            return checkerproxy_list

        checkerproxy_list = self.parse_checkerproxy(html)
        return checkerproxy_list

    def parse_checkerproxy(self, html):
        ''' Only get elite proxies from checkerproxy '''
        ips = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
            if len(tr) == 19:
                ip_found = False
                elite = False
                ip_port = None
                tds = tr.findAll('td')
                for td in tds:
                    if ':' in td.text:
                        ip_found = True
                        ip_port_re = re.match('(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}', td.text)
                        if ip_port_re:
                            ip_port = ip_port_re.group()
                        if not ip_port:
                            ip_found = False
                    if 'Elite' in td.text:
                        elite = True
                    if ip_found == True and elite == True:
                        ips.append(str(ip_port))
                        break
        return ips

    def letushide_req(self):
        ''' Make the request to the proxy site and create a master list from that site '''
        letushide_ips = []
        for i in xrange(1,20): # can search maximum of 20 pages
            try:
                url = 'http://letushide.com/filter/http,hap,all/%s/list_of_free_HTTP_High_Anonymity_proxy_servers' % str(i)
                r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
                html = r.text
                ips = self.parse_letushide(html)

                # Check html for a link to the next page
                if '/filter/http,hap,all/%s/list_of_free_HTTP_High_Anonymity_proxy_servers' % str(i+1) in html:
                    pass
                else:
                    letushide_ips.append(ips)
                    break
                letushide_ips.append(ips)
            except:
                print '[!] Failed get reply from %s' % url
                break

        # Flatten list of lists (1 list containing 1 list of ips for each page)
        letushide_list = [item for sublist in letushide_ips for item in sublist]
        return letushide_list

    def parse_letushide(self, html):
        ''' Parse out list of IP:port strings from the html '''
        # \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}  -  matches IP addresses
        # </a></td><td>  -  is in between the IP and the port
        # .*?<  -  match all text (.) for as many characters as possible (*) but don't be greedy (?) and stop at the next greater than (<)
        raw_ips = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}</a></td><td>.*?<', html)
        ips = []
        for ip in raw_ips:
            ip = ip.replace('</a></td><td>', ':')
            ip = ip.strip('<')
            ips.append(ip)
        return ips

    def gatherproxy_req(self):
        url = 'http://gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite'
        try:
            r = requests.get(url, headers = self.headers)
            lines = r.text.splitlines()
        except:
            print '[!] Failed get reply from %s' % url
            gatherproxy_list = []
            return gatherproxy_list

        gatherproxy_list = self.parse_gp(lines)
        return gatherproxy_list

    def parse_gp(self, lines):
        ''' Parse the raw scraped data '''
        gatherproxy_list = []
        for l in lines:
            if 'proxy_ip' in l.lower():
                l = l.replace('gp.insertPrx(', '')
                l = l.replace(');', '')
                l = l.replace('null', 'None')
                l = l.strip()
                l = ast.literal_eval(l)

                proxy = '%s:%s' % (l["PROXY_IP"], l["PROXY_PORT"])
                gatherproxy_list.append(proxy)
                #ctry = l["PROXY_COUNTRY"]
        return gatherproxy_list

    def proxy_checker(self):
        ''' Concurrency stuff here '''
        jobs = [gevent.spawn(self.proxy_checker_req, proxy) for proxy in self.proxy_list]
        try:
            gevent.joinall(jobs)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit('[-] Ctrl-C caught, exiting')

    def proxy_checker_req(self, proxy):
        ''' See how long each proxy takes to open each URL '''
        proxyip = str(proxy.split(':', 1)[0])

        # A lot of proxy checker sites give a different final octet for some reason
        #proxy_split = proxyip.split('.')
        #first_3_octets = '.'.join(proxy_split[:3])+'.'

        results = []
        urls = ['http://danmcinerney.org/ip.php', 'http://myip.dnsdynamic.org', 'https://www.astrill.com/what-is-my-ip-address.php', 'http://danmcinerney.org/headers.php']
        for url in urls:
            try:
                check = requests.get(url,
                                    headers = self.headers,
                                    proxies = {'http':'http://'+proxy,
                                               'https':'http://'+proxy},
                                    timeout = 15)

                time_or_error = str(check.elapsed)
                html = check.text
                time_or_error = self.html_handler(time_or_error, html, url)
                url = self.url_shortener(url)
                results.append((time_or_error, proxy, url))

            except Exception as e:
                time_or_error = self.error_handler(str(e))
                url = self.url_shortener(url)
                results.append((time_or_error, proxy, url))

        self.print_handler(results, proxyip)

    def html_handler(self, time_or_error, html, url):
        ''' Check the html for errors and if none are found return time to load page '''

        html_lines = html.splitlines()
        leng = len(html_lines)
        ipre = '(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'

        # Both of these urls just return the ip and nothing else
        if url in ['http://danmcinerney.org/ip.php', 'http://myip.dnsdynamic.org']:
            if leng == 1:  # Should return 1 line of html
                match = re.match(ipre, html)
                if match:
                    if self.externalip in html:
                        time_or_error = 'Err: Page loaded; proxy failed'
                else:
                    time_or_error = 'Err: Page loaded; proxy failed'
            else:
                time_or_error = 'Err: Page loaded; proxy failed'
            return time_or_error

        # This is the SSL page
        if 'astrill' in url:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            ip = soup.find("td", { "colspan": 2 }).text # the ip is the only on with colspan = 2
            match = re.match(ipre, ip)
            if match:
                if self.externalip in ip:
                    time_or_error = 'Err: Page loaded; proxy failed'
            else:
                time_or_error = 'Err: Page loaded; proxy failed'
            return time_or_error

        if '/headers' in url:
            # check for proxy headers
            proxy_headers = ['via: ', 'forwarded: ', 'x-forwarded-for', 'client-ip']
            if leng > 15: # 15 is arbitrary, I just don't think you'll ever see more than 15 headers
                time_or_error = 'Err: headers not returned'
                return time_or_error
            for l in html_lines:
                for h in proxy_headers:
                    if h in l.lower():
                        time_or_error = 'Err: Proxy headers found'
                        return time_or_error
            time_or_error = 'Passed: elite proxy'
            return time_or_error

    def print_handler(self, results, proxyip):
        if self.show_all:
            country_code = self.get_country_code(proxyip)
            self.printer(results, country_code)
            self.print_counter += 1
        else:
            passed_all = self.passed_all_tests(results)
            if passed_all:
                country_code = self.get_country_code(proxyip)
                self.printer(results, country_code)
                self.print_counter += 1

        if self.show_num:
            self.limiter()

    def printer(self, results, country_code):
        ''' Creates the output '''
        counter = 0
        if not self.quiet:
            print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'
        for r in results:
            counter += 1
            time_or_error = r[0]
            proxy = r[1]
            url = r[2]

            if self.quiet:
                if counter % 4 == 0: #################### THIS results is a list of 4 tuples each, so proxies will repeat 4 times
                    #print proxy
                    global listz
                    listz.append(proxy)
            else:
                # Only print the proxy once, on the second print job
                if counter == 1:
                    print '%s | %s | %s | %s' % (proxy.ljust(21), country_code.ljust(3), url.ljust(21), time_or_error)
                else:
                    print '%s | %s | %s | %s' % (' '.ljust(21), '   ', url.ljust(21), time_or_error)

    def get_country_code(self, proxyip):
        ''' Get the 3 letter country code of the proxy using geoiptool.com
        Would use the geoip library, but it requires a local DB and what
        is the point of that hassle other than marginal speed improvement '''
        cc_line_found = False
        cc = 'N/A'

        try:
            r = requests.get('http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=%s' % proxyip, headers=self.headers)
            html = r.text
            html_lines = html.splitlines()
            for l in html_lines:
                if cc_line_found == True:
                    cc = l.split('(', 1)[1].split(')', 1)[0]
                    break
                if 'country code:' in l.lower():
                    cc_line_found = True
        except:
            pass
        return cc

    def error_handler(self, e):
        if 'Cannot connect' in e:
            time_or_error = 'Err: Cannot connect to proxy'
        elif 'timed out' in e.lower():
            time_or_error = 'Err: Timed out'
        elif 'retries exceeded' in e:
            time_or_error = 'Err: Max retries exceeded'
        elif 'Connection reset by peer' in e:
            time_or_error = 'Err: Connection reset by peer'
        elif 'readline() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)' in e:
            time_or_error = 'Err: SSL error'
        else:
            time_or_error = 'Err: ' + e
        return time_or_error

    def url_shortener(self, url):
        if 'ip.php' in url:
            url = 'danmcinerney.org'
        elif 'headers.php' in url:
            url = 'Header check'
        elif 'dnsdynamic' in url:
            url = 'dnsdynamic.org'
        elif 'astrill' in url:
            url = 'https://astrill.com'
        return url

    def passed_all_tests(self, results):
        for r in results:
            time_or_error= r[0]
            if 'Err:' in time_or_error:
                global testx
                testx = 50
                return False
        return True
    def limiter(self):
        testx = 0
        ''' Kill the script if user supplied limit of successful proxy attempts (-s argument) is reached '''
        if self.print_counter >= int(self.show_num):
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Exactly which Python 2.7 version do you have? And which version of `gevent` Because IIRC there was a bug in `threading` that was fixed relatively recently, and backported to 2.7, that had something to do with either the active-thread dict or the thread-local-storage dict, and even if you have that fix, there could be an equivalent bug in `gevent`'s patch…

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6 (Mar 22 2014) and gevent 1.0.1...both are up to date :-/

Comment: Python 2.7 is up to 2.7.8, so 2.7.6 is not up to date. (But I don't know for sure when that bug was fixed, or whether it had anything to do with what you're seeing, it's just a vague hunch.)